# Where do Model classes go in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2. Coming from Zend background, I do not see any folder for Models. How do Models and Controllers communicate?

What if I do not want to use Doctrine. Even if I use Doctrine, where will the Models live and how can they communicate with controllers?

Symfony website has some good documentation about symfony2, but it is not on par with the documentation I noticed for symfony1.X .The official documentation does not have what namespaces should be added when using different doctrine methods.
Thanks for the community in advance for the tips.

Comment: Please post a more specific question than one asking for a complete symfony2 tutorial.

Comment: Refining the question:  1)Where are models placed inside symfony2 structure   2) How is it that I do not see any documentation for communication between models and controllers in official documentation.  3)If I can be any mroe specific than this, I would know the answer by myself.

Comment: Symfony has a very good documentation especially for newcomers, please read it. E.g. start with [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html) or with [this one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html).

Comment: Thanks 1ed for the references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Symfony2 is really about providing the tools for the Controller part, the View part, but not the Model part. It's up to you to create your model by hand or use any other tool, like an ORM.
>
> -- Fabien Potencier ([source](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2))

#### But how do I communicate with the database without a model?

You can choose your way of doing it. You can create your custom Models and use them, or you can use DataMappers or something else. The Symfony2 Standard Edition includes the Doctrine and Propel ORMs. Doctrine is used by default.

Read more about those ORM and how you can use them inside Symfony2 here: [doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) or [propel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html).

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I have to deal with cross database joins and when I map my exiting databases with doctrine,symfony console commnads the      " php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert "  command results in an Entity folder with entities from multiple databases when I run it with different default connections. Is it possible to write a cross database join using doctrine? To me this looks impossible for now, as the connection settings in parameters.yml and config.yml have a database name specified and to query we have to use these connections

Comment: You can use [multiple entity manages](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)... but AFAIK Doctrine2 does not support cross database joins.

Comment: Using Mysql as your datasource you can fudge cross-database joins by manually adding the database name as a prefix in the entity annotations where needed. i.e. `@ORM\Table(name="database.table")` This has the effect of adding `database.table` to the SQL instead of just `table`.

Answer (score 17):

You can create Model manually.

**MODELS**:

- Create new dir inside your bundle (Model)
- Create MyModel
- Set **namespace**  (company\mybundle\models)
- Set Doctrine and use entities (**use**)
- In your model put **DQL**

**CONTROLLERS**:

- `use company\mybundle\models\mymodel;`

  > ```
  > public function getRecentUserAction ($max = 10)  
  > {
  >      $user = new MyModel();
  >      $list = $user->getRecentUser($max) // DQL
  >     return $this->render('CompanyBundle:controller:index.html.twig',array('list'=>$list));
  > }
  > ```

Comment: Thanx a lot! This answer is way more practical than Wouter's anwser. Helped me to finally get Models autoloaded in Symfony2 (with my ZF background).

Comment: I'm still confused about where the link between the model and entity happens to persist data to your database. Can you provide an example of a model to show this.